# Two mst in one graph, require exactly the same weights on the edgs?

Tags: data-structures, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

I need to find two different minimum spanning tree in one graph, I wanted to know if it must be that for every weight of a edge that exists in the first minimum spanning tree there is a edge with the same weight in the second minimum spanning tree.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a programming question

Comment: why? Obviously this is a programming question

Comment: Hint: Take a very simple graph, such as the graph with 3 vertices and 3 edges and weights respectively 1,2 and 3 on the first, second and third edges. Step 1: Find two distinct minimum spanning trees on this graph. Step 2: What do you observe, and does that answer your question?

Comment: I only received one minimal spanning tree

Comment: Fair enough, so try with a more complicated graph.

Comment: OK, show the code you have written so far?  I cannot even imagine a code that could prove your hypothesis.  (  It could be DISPROVED by a code that generated a counterexample, but never proved )

Comment: Try with this graph: https://i.imgur.com/pW0roWY.png

Comment: @ravenspoint Sometimes there are other approaches to problems than just spewing out code...

Comment: @Stef  For this problem one of the other approaches is needed.  Which is why this question is on the wrong site.

Comment: @ravenspoint Then a possible course of action would be to vote for it to be migrated. Voting to close won't make it move to the right site.

Comment: This question is answered here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2204/do-the-minimum-spanning-trees-of-a-weighted-graph-have-the-same-number-of-edges (the answer is yes)

Comment: @stef I tried that.  Couldn't get it to work.